# How to find the x and y coordinates of an element after rotateX(20deg) and rotateY(20deg)?

Tags: javascript, css

HTML

```
<div id="plane"></div>
```

CSS

```
#plane {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

I can see the `div` (square) has 4 corners (A,B,C,D).

How can I find the new x and y co-ordinates of point A after rotation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.getBoundingClientRect()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). It will give you the element's `top`/`right`/`left`/`bottom` positions along with the `height`/`width` [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2urw554/).

For instance:

```
var plane = document.getElementById('plane');
console.log(plane.getBoundingClientRect());
```

Output:

```
{
    bottom: 318.5572204589844
    height: 319.11444091796875
    left: 17.106414794921875
    right: 300.8935852050781
    top: -0.5572299957275391
    width: 283.78717041015625
}
```

```js
var plane = document.getElementById('plane');

console.log('Before: ', plane.getBoundingClientRect());
plane.classList.add('transformed');

console.log('After: ', plane.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
#plane {
    border: 1px solid;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
#plane.transformed {
    transform:rotateX(20deg) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="plane"></div>
```